# Uncorrelated random variables and their joint distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, sampling

If I have two random variables that are uncorrelated with each other,does sampling from their individual distributions separately and combining them to form a vector give a sample from their joint distribution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Take $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X^2$. Then $\mathbb{E}(XY)=\mathbb{E}(X^3)=0$. And hence $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. But they are not independent. So, sampling from $X$ automatically implies sampling from $Y$ and thus the joint density does not factor into the densities of the separate variables.

So, the answer is no.

Comment: What If the two variables are independent and uncorrelated? Can we do it if its the case?

Comment: Yes, independence implies uncorrelatedness and moreover is equivalent to factorizability of the joint density into the separate one variable densities.